# How to display a controller variable in view(blade)

Tags: laravel-blade, laravel-5.8

I have a variable generated by the controller in laravel 5.8, I want to display this variable on the view

I have tried using the conventional {!! $variable !!} but it returns

@section('page_heading',"System Dashboard | {!! $region !!}")

I expect to get Kalipso Dashboard |Northern Region but instead am getting Kalipso Dashboard |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be set as below
Suppose value of $region = 'Your custom string message here.';

@section('page_heading',"System Dashboard | {{ $region }}")

Comment: this displays 
System Dashboard | <?php echo e(West Africa); ?>

Comment: This will also work.
@section('page_heading',"System Dashboard | " . $region)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. 
 Used @section('page_heading',"System Dashboard | $region ")